# Why the "focusin" event is called twice in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In Chrome, when the focus tab is lost and when it appears, the "focusin" event doubles again. "Focusin" is displayed twice in the console. The code is below.

There is no such problem in Firefox.

Tell me please, with what it can be connected and how can I fix it?

```
$('span[data-field="DestinationGoogleMap"]').on('focusin', 'input', () => {
  console.log('focusin');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code, I did something like this and couldnt reproduce your bug: (could you share also the html code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<span data-field="DestinationGoogleMap">
    <input type="" name="">
</span>

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('span[data-field="DestinationGoogleMap"]').on('focusin', 'input', () => {
  console.log('focusin');
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]